# Mysql get Version value that between a Version range

Tags: mysql, sql, version

I have a query that works as:

```
@v='2.2.2'
select version FROM app_versions as V where @v between V.min_ver and V.max_ver;
```

Where the version is expressed as a string of format "x.y.z".

I can't write a query that work right and readable. Is there a better solution for mysql?

```
Famous test cases (min_ver -> max_ver):
1.10.1 -> 2.3.3
2.2.100 -> 2.2.111
```

Comment: Probably best to split the column into mayor, minor, build columns

Comment: that too long for a query :'(

Comment: Can you share your app_versions ddl ?

Comment: @TuLeAnh: I meant change the table definiton to avoid such problems.

Comment: @SelVazi
INSERT INTO table_name (version, min_ver, max_ver)
VALUES ('1.1.1', '1.0.0', '2.0.0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly the question, why not using [INET_ATON(expr)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) ,

> Given the dotted-quad representation of an IPv4 network address as a
> string, returns an integer that represents the numeric value of the
> address in network byte order (big endian). INET_ATON() returns NULL
> if it does not understand its argument, or if expr is NULL

```
select av.* 
from app_versions  av 
where INET_ATON('2.2.2') between INET_ATON(av.min_ver) and INET_ATON(av.max_ver);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/btp2IhXb

Comment: Thank you, I have solved the problem but in case of mayor, minor can > 255 (a bit changeling)

Comment: Is not working if we search on 2.3.20 !

Comment: @SelVazi can you explain why isn't working for `2.3.20` ? In my example `2.3.20` isn't in any of the range

Comment: 2.3.20 should be in the same range as 2.2.2 but your query is returning null in this case

Comment: @SelVazi no it shouldn't as 2.3.20 isn't in the same range as  2.2.2. 2.3.20 > 2.3.3.

Comment: As far as I know 1.10.1 < 2.3.20 < 2.3.3